# Solving some type of Mixed Integer Programming in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have a rather complicated optimisation problem I want to solve in matlab, I posted it on math.stackexchange.com since it supports LaTeX maths display,

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/210166/some-type-of-mixed-integer-nonlinear-programming-problem

I would really appreciate it if anyone can give me some suggestions on that.

Comment: Is the decision variable is just T?  And it is constrained by s(T)=D?

Comment: @Clark, yes, except those constants, all other variables are functions of t(time).

Answer (score 1):

I didn't go into much details of the minimization problem you described, but it made me think of http://www2.maths.ox.ac.uk/chebfun. It is an open source numeric computing toolbox that at least superficially seems interesting. Maybe you can use it to solve your problem.